# receiving nill image with nsdata received by parser: foundCDATA ,

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata, nsxmlparser, cdata

I am creating a uiimage with nsdata by the following way

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock{
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock];}
```

but i am getting nill image ,kindly help me.

Thanks.

Comment: can you try replacing last line of you code with UIImage* image = [UIImage initWithData:CDATABlock];  ??

Comment: I got following error after trying your solution :  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIImage initWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Answer (score 0):

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:CDATABlock];
```

Try the above one.

Comment: this is also not creating image,i don't know where i am making mistake,even i am getting nsdata but it is not creating image

Comment: @WaleedBashirHeraj here you load ur image as a URL. That will helps you. Convert NSData to NSURL. From there you can get the image.